How to Migrate TFVC code from TFS to AzureDevOps
I'm trying to migrate projects from TeamFoundationServer (2017) to AzureDevOps Services. I'm using nkdagility to migrate workitems and testcases. I want to migrate my TFVC repositories to AzureDevOps services as TFVC repos with full history.
Any work around or tool which will help me do that?
We tried converting TFVC to gitVC , then migrating gitVC repos to AzureDevOps and then converting it back to TFVC.

I don't think there is a tool to migrate only TFVC projet source code to one in ADO.
But there is a tool to migrate a whole TFS server to ADO: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops
And a pdf from Microsoft:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274

We tried converting TFVC to gitVC, then migrating gitVC repos to AzureDevOps and then converting it back to TFVC.

That is not a satisfying solution. Except if you have a very simple history (with only one branch and maybe other constraints), this type of migration will be either impossible or without a good fidelity result (and I know what I'm talking about as the maintainer of git-tfs tool).
But as TFVC is a 2nd class option in ADO, with features only available for git repositories and TFVC no more actively developed, you should think twice about staying on it or taking the occasion to switch to git which is a much more future proof solution.

The easiest way to migrate from server to service is using the official data migration tool, which can migrate all of your work items, work item history, TFVC changesets, TFVC changeset history, Git data, build definitions, build history, and other data stored in the collection. If you want to use it, upgrade your server to Azure DevOps Server 2022.0.1 or Azure DevOps Server 2022.1. See the detailed info from Migrate data from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services.
There is a third-party extension OpsHub Migrator for Microsoft Azure DevOps (OM4ADO), which seems can migrate TFVC from server to service.
If you want to convert TFVC to git, you can use git tfs. And convert git back to TFVC, you can use git-tf and refer to the followings:

Convert Git repository to TFVC version control.
Migrate Git repository to new TFVC repository.

